# Adjust height of an iframe

Tags: html

Actually, I want to adjust the height of an iframe according to the height of the column dynamically.Html code-

```css
.demo{
        margin-bottom: -99999px;
        padding-bottom: 99999px;
        background-color:#efefef;

    }

    #equalheight {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div id="equalheight">
            <div class="col-xs-6 demo"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src= "{{ $name }}" ></iframe></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 demo"><?php echo var_dump($data);?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the problem is that the size of iframe doesn't change.Only background size changes according to the var_dump($data).I want to adjust iframe size according to the file(var_sump($data)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to the parent and `height: 100%;` to the frame

```css
.demo {
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

#equalheight {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.embed-responsive-item {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">   
    <div id="equalheight">
        <div class="col-xs-6 demo"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src= "{{ $name }}" ></iframe></div>            <div class="col-xs-6 demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dignissim eleifend eros, non condimentum nulla pellentesque vel. Cras pretium dolor arcu, eget iaculis enim cursus ac. Proin ornare quam nibh, eget sodales urna consectegtur vitae. Cras justo tellus, mollis vel euismod non, vehicula eu urna. Praesent non mattis dui. Sed ut felis nec nunc dignissim porttitor sed in augue. Suspendisse sed velit ut sapien gravida scelerisque sit amet nec neque. Sed mauris dui, interdum id augue vitae, faucibus sollicitudin ante. </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your iframe size container and not just your iframe size.